# React-Router: Why won't <Link> component's onClick handler dispatch my action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I would like React-Router's `<Link>`to fire a function on click but it looks like `<Link>` is navigating to the next page before the function has a chance to fire.

My component that looks similar to this:

```
<Link to={`/path/to/${foo}`} onClick={() => myFunc(foo, bar)}>
  <div>This is my Link</div>
</Link>
```

`foo` and `bar` are props that have been passed down from parent components.

However, if I call `e.preventDefault`, any subsequent functions work just fine:

```
<Link
    to={`/path/to/${foo}`}
    onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault(); console.log('This works!')}>
  <div>This is my Link</div>
</Link>
```

I imagine I could do something similar to this, then programmatically navigate to my route but there has to be a better (i.e. less hack-y) way of achieving this effect.

Does anyone have any suggestions, that might help me?

Comment: `<Link onClick={function() { console.log('a') }} ... >` seem to work fine. Show please `myFunc` implementation. Isn't there something async?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr It's a standard action creator that returns an object. Also, it's an arrow function expression.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dispatch(myFunc(foo, bar))` then?

Comment: What action do you want the `onClick` function to perform? Do some action _then_ redirect to the route listed in the `to` property?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr `myFunc` is already wrapped into a dispatch call by react-redux.

Comment: @Ashley'CptLemming'Wilson I would like `onClick` to dispatch an action before the redirect but it seems like the redirect interrupts that?

Answer (score 0):

This is directly not a solution, but you can try instead of using `Link` component, use simple `a` element, and move to the needed route inside `onClick` handler:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

<a onClick={
  browserHistory.push(`/path/to/${foo}`)
  myFunc(foo, bar)
}>
  <div>This is my Link</div>
</a>
```